# Comma operator in condition of loop in C

Tags: c, comma-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<0, 5; i++)
        printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

I am unable to understand the `i<0, 5` part in the condition of the `for` loop.

Even if I make it `i>0, 5`, there's no change in output.

How does this work?

Comment: The linked article says "Because the comma operator discards its first operand, it is generally only useful where the first operand has desirable side effects"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comma operator evaluates `i<0` Or `i>0` and ignores. Hence, it's always the `5` that's present in the condition.

So it's equivalent to:

```
for(i=0;5;i++)
```

Comment: Someone commented this answer is wrong. Now the comment is gone & I am left wondering who it is.

Comment: reamant from the time you stated it evaluates `i>5`, probably. I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: @JanDvorak perhaps, the confusion comes from i<0 or i>0 .. It's simply OP asked even if change the condition it still gives same output. Thats why I added the `for` loop.

Comment: Since those who have commented didn't downvote, I'd appreciate if the anonymous downvoter can explain his/her reason.

Comment: Thanks @KingsIndian..!!
by my vote the downvote of anonymous got compensated..
But I don't get one thing, why does it ignore i<0 or i>0, & why will it return 5 always...
After accepting it always returns 5, how does this work then (i=0,5,i++)

Please Ignore my dumbness, consider me a noob.

Thanks Again..!!

Comment: @user81910 Comma operator evaluates and leaves only the last one as result. So if if you `(i<0,5)` it evaluates the condition `i<0` and ignores. Then evaluates `5` which is simply `5`. So the resulting condition in the `for` loop is equivalent to the above in my answer. The same happens if you have `i>0, 5` as well.

Comment: @user81910 `(i=0,5,i++)` in for loop would be an error. If it's an expression elsewhere then it'll first initialize `i=0` then evaluate a `5` and then do `i++`. Which is equal to: `i=0; 5; i++;` But if you have `j=(i=0,5,i++);` then the same steps will be the same and assign the result of `i++` to `j`. i.e. `0` in this case. if you have `j=(i=8,5,i++)` then j will be `8`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant (i=0;5;i++)

Comment: That's very simple. The condition is always true i.e. it's `5`. So it'll be an infinite loop. In C, `0` is false, anything else is true. So, if you have `for(i=0;1;i++)` or `for(i=0;-1;i++)` they are all the same & will go into an infinite loop unless you have break statement inside the loop :)

Comment: Finally, I got it.!
Thank you very much...!!
Chose your answer as it was to the point(where all my confusions lied)

Answer (score 21):

### On topic

The comma operator will always yield the last value in the comma separated list.

Basically it's a binary operator that evaluates the left hand value but discards it, then evaluates the right hand value and returns it.

If you chain multiple of these they will eventually yield the last value in the chain.

As per anatolyg's comment, this is useful if you want to evaluate the left hand value before the right hand value (if the left hand evaluation has a desirable side effect).

For example `i < (x++, x/2)` would be a sane way to use that operator because you're affecting the right hand value with the repercussions of the left hand value evaluation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

### Sidenote: did you ever hear of this curious operator?

```
int x = 100;
while(x --> 0) {
    // do stuff with x
}
```

It's just another way of writing `x-- > 0`.

Comment: So to be clear, in the OP there's no difference between using i<0,5 and i<5 since the 0 just evaluates to 0 and doesn't do anything?

Comment: The comma operator has the least priority, so `i < x++, x/2` will only return false if `x` is 0 or 1. The comparison is redundant.

Comment: Precisely, it looks nifty though doesn't it?

Comment: @Jan you're assuming `i` is incremented by `1`. It's not necessarily the case.

Comment: Incrementing a `for` loop by `4` is a very common thing to do in C code written for microcontrollers that support 4 pipelines.

Comment: `x` is incremented, then compared to `i`, then `x/2` is returned. The value of `i` does not affect the result in any way.

Comment: Oh sorry you meant that bracing would be necessary. My bad. I assumed `i < 0,5` compares `i` to `5` not to `0` so I assumed operator precedence is ok in this case.

Comment: Still, why use `i < (x++, x/2)` when you can use `i < ++x / 2`

Comment: @Jan i was trying to give the man an example based on his own code, a better example would be `(call_function_that_affects(x),x/2)` which cannot be replaced with syntactic sugar.

Comment: The `-->` operator is cute :-) I should use it more :-)

Comment: "i = (a,b)"  stores b into i      while on the other hand
"i = a,b"  stores a into i

That means parentheses do matter. Right?

"i < (0,5)" will compare i with 5 while 
"i < 0,5" will compare i with 0

Now I got to know how this code works.. thanks for your help Mihai Stancu.. Thanks for the side note.. learned something that may sometimes confuse if encountered in viva or exam..

Answer (score 4):

The coma operator is done to the initialization and to the increment part, to do something like `for(i=0,j=20;i<j;i++,j--)`, if you do it in the comparation part it will evaluate the last one (as it was already answered before)

Answer (score 3):

`i<0,5` will always evaluate to `5`, as always the right expression will be returned for `ex1,ex2` .

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator is intended for cases where the first operand has some side effects. It's just an idiom, meant to make your code more readable. It has no effect on the evaluation of the conditional.

For example,

```
for (i = 0; i<(i++, 5); i++) {
    // something
}
```

will increment `i`, and then check if `i<5`.

Comment: What is the relative priority of `<` and `,` again? I don't think it will _ever_ evaluate `i<5`

Comment: @JanDvorak Right. The parsing is `((i < i++), 5)`, so `i` is compared to `i++` (or not, the compiler may reduce that part to simply `i++`), and the result is always 5.

Comment: From wikipedia (I haven't confirmed with a compiler) "the comma operator has the lowest precedence of any C operator"

Comment: @mfrankli And that means that the `<` binds tighter than the `,`, so `i < i++` is the first expression, `5` the second.

Comment: right, per Mihai Stancu's answer, parens are necessary to make it really make sense. i'll update fwiw

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
 for(i=0; i<0,i<5; i++)
    printf("%d ", i);
```

then the last condition wins and that code block will print

0
1
2
3
4