# Odd if statements

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, if-statement

I didn't think these if's would compile but they do:

```
if (a>>b&&c&&d)

if (month==1,2,3,5,7,9,10)
```

The first I'm clueless about. In the second statement is the comma supposed to be an (||) or operator ? 
Syntax wise was it always this way or was it introduced some time ago ?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: The first has a bitshift and logical ands, and the comma operator is not the same as logical or, otherwise it wouldn't exist. It's not hard to research the comma operator.

Comment: For the second one see [return list of values between parenthesis (10, 20, 30, 40)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001349/return-list-of-values-between-parenthesis-10-20-30-40)

Comment: Just because it compiles, does not mean it's doing what you think it's doing. Research the operators you're using before you use them if you're unsure - there's plenty of questions on this already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comma Operator in Conditon of Loop in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959415/comma-operator-in-conditon-of-loop-in-c)

Comment: You are right, I should've searched for the comma operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (a>>b && c && d)
```

it is equal to

```
if ((a>>b) && c && d)
```

if the result of `a` shifted right `b` times evaluates to a `bool`, `c` and `d` also evaluates to `bool` respectively, then all these booleans will be *AND*-ed to each other.

In your context, the all expressions within commas will be evaluated and then the last expression will be passed to `if` expression:

```
if (month==1,2,3,5,7,9,10) -> is equal to
if (2,3,5,7,9,10)          -> is equal to
if (3,5,7,9,10)            -> is equal to
if (5,7,9,10)              -> is equal to
if (7,9,10)                -> is equal to
if (9,10)                  -> is equal to
if (10)
```

which is always `true`.

It's not suppose to be `||` or `&&`. If you want *OR* or *AND* write it like below:

```
if (month==1 || month==2 || month==3 || ....)
```

or

```
if (month==1 && month==2 && month==3 && ....)
// Also month can not simultaneously be equal to more than one value!
// then, it's equal to
if (false)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first if statement would be evaluated like:

```
if(((a >> b) && c) && d)
```

Essentially bitshift `a` by `b` bits and then logical and with `c` and then with `d`

The second is the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) which will evaluate the first term and throw it away, then the second, and so on and return the result of the final term. So in our case the statement is equivalent to:

```
if(10)
```

which is always true.

Comment: so it would just be 10 then. I altered my answer. Thanks.