# Extra letter being displayed in Password Field

Tags: c++, borland-c++

```
void createAccount(){

        int i=0;
        cout<<"\nEnter new Username: ";
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
        cin.getline(newUsername,20);
        cout<<"\nEnter new Password: ";

        for(i=0;i<10,newPassword[i]!=8;i++){

            newPassword[i]=getch();    //for taking a char. in array-'newPassword' at i'th place
            if(newPassword[i]==13)     //checking if user press's enter
                break;                 //breaking the loop if enter is pressed
            cout<<"*";                 //as there is no char. on screen we print '*'
        }

     newPassword[i]='\0';       //inserting null char. at the end

     cout<<"\n"<<newPassword;
}
```

In function `createAccount();` the user is entering `char newUsername[20]` and `char newPassword[20]`. However, to display the password as ****** I've implemented a different way for entering `newPassword`. However, when I try displaying `newPassword` the output has an extra letter that magically appears in the command box without me entering anything.

### OUTPUT

```
Enter new Username: anzam
Enter new Password: ****** //entered azeez but the first * is already there in command box without user inputting anything

Mazeez //displaying newPassword
```

If someone could help me I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: The loop condition `i<10, newPassword[i]!=8` is dubious.

Comment: I believe the extra * you are seeing is the blank char. what are the actual chars you getting if you try to examine the newPassword array?

Comment: I would move the backspace check into the loop for clarity in reading.

for(i=0;i<10;i++){ if(newPassword[i]==8) continue; (rest of logic...)}

Comment: The comma should probably be changed to `&&`. See: [Comma Operator in Conditon of Loop in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959415/comma-operator-in-conditon-of-loop-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` has been incremented at the end of the loop. The easiest way to fix this is to initialize `password` to zero

```
char newPassword[20];
memset(newPassword, 0, 20);

for (i = 0; i < 10; )
{
    int c = getch();
    if (c == 13)
        break;

    //check if character is valid
    if (c < ' ') continue;
    if (c > '~') continue;

    newPassword[i] = c;
    cout << "*";
    i++; //increment here
}
```

Comment: 1) If <enter> is pressed, the last increment will not be executed. The `break` jumps out of the loop immediately. 2) In the sample output, the offending char is at the start of the string.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp , I think I fixed it now, I should have just stayed away from this :)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani that seemed to have done it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

One problem might be that you intermix `conio` (`getch`) and `iostream` (`cin`), and they might not be synchronized. Try adding this line at the beginning of your program:

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio ();
```

Also, you read password until you see `13`, but, if I'm not mistaken, in reality in windows pressing enter produces first `10` and then `13`, so you might want to check for both as a stop condition.